# Affine Cipher Decryption in Python

Tags: python, cryptography

I am not sure if here is a right place to ask , as it is  about coding and also cryptography.

I have this simple code to encrypt chars.However I could not find how to decrypt by knowing the key . I know the logic of decryption but I could not write the inverse algorithm in Python. It prints A:I , as an example.

```
 def affine(a, b):
 for i in range(26):
    print chr(i+65) + ": " + chr(((a*i+b)%26)+65)
    affine(5, 8)
```

And another question is , what is the logic of adding 65 to the char index? Thank you.

Comment: Where did you find this script? If you want a simple cryptographic method, I'll recommend you XOR cryptography (weak)

Comment: Actually I need to use Affine , not other methods.

Comment: The ASCII value of 'A' is 65, so `i + 65` maps 0 to A, 1 to B etc.